# How to get list of env variables from the root folder to jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, configuration, environment-variables

> Using configure option, when we check the environment variables, we
>   get only the variables which are available with in the folder or job.
>   But, I want to get complete list of env variable from the root folder
>   to the folder/job, which I want to see.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use the **printenv** command for list system Variable:

```
printenv
```

and also An easy way to obtain the Jenkins environment variables list from your local installation is to append env-vars.html to the server's URL. the URL would be

`http://{jenkins_url}/env-vars.html`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ***environment variables*** are not folder/directory specific, but user specific, that means, for any user its loaded when the user logins into the shell or source the profile which contains the added environment variables (like ~/.bash_profile). So, if your environment variables are present at root directory, it should be present at the folder/job level as well unless your new bash where this job is running, doesn't loads the environment variable, for which you can test them using the below commands in the job to see if those variables are present or not:

```
pwd
echo $PATH
env
```

if not present, you can source your profile in the job using `. .bash_profile` and check if all variables are present or not